# chkdsk An unspecified error occurred (696e647863686b2e 20e4) & (6672732e637878 5e4) also missing from defragmenter

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, chkdsk, defragment

I keep running chkdsk on my HDD (it's a disk for games) but it keep failing in one way or another and need to it ever time it starts up.

I've got several pastebins of chkdsk I've done, these are the logs:

1. [chkdsk 10/03/2021 /offlinescanandfix](https://pastebin.com/Ve2wKSRy)
2. [chkdsk 11/03/2021 /offlinescanandfix](https://pastebin.com/YCmarbrj)
3. [chkdsk 11/03/2021 /x](https://pastebin.com/1RwVvp5F)

This is a CrystalDiskInfo

[image: CrystalDiskInfo screenshot]

It also fails to show up on the disk defragmenter

[image: disk defragmenter]

The model is a WDC WD1001FALS-00J7B1

Windows OS Version is 10.0.19042 Build 19042

I'm not fully sure what I should be doing here and I'm honestly feeling quite lost. And yes it won't run my games correctly I get errors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably lucky it doesn't show up on the disk defragger; because defragging a drive in that state would probably kill it stone dead.

The drive is failing.

As it's only got games on it, you'd do best just replacing the drive & reinstalling the games. You could try a rescue copy, but for replacable data it's not worth the effort.

If you have saves on there, which you shouldn't they should be on C:\ then you could try copying them off first.

btw, chkdsk doesn't care at all about your data. Its job is to get the drive back into a state it can continue to function, not to rescue data. It also doesn't really have the concept of 'giving up'. Each time it tries to fix a failing drive it's going to damage something else in the attempt.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into getting a new drive now. It's a surprise that it's failing because it was largely unused and just left in a attic for years. Gonna copy the important bits (save files etc) asap

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive is failing and should be replaced. Back up any information on it, and then make arrangements to replace it.

There is not any practical way to save a hard drive and make it good. That is why I say to replace it.